# Infinite loop with get function

Tags: c++

Can Anyone tell me that what's wrong with using get function here instead of getline. Get works perfectly in reading a single line without any loop. Why it isn't working here. It results in infinite loop.

```
int main() {
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("Myfile.txt", ios::trunc);
outfile <<"aabc"<<endl;
outfile <<"Hello Helloo"<<endl;
outfile <<"3abc"<<endl;
outfile <<"Somee text here  "<<endl;
outfile.close();

ifstream infile;
infile.open("Myfile.txt");
char ch[20];

while(!infile.eof()) {
    infile.get(ch,20);
    cout<<ch;
}
infile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When called with a `char*`, as in your `get(ch,20)`, the `get` method will read up to 19 characters or until it reaches a delimiter (`\n` by default).

The delimiting character is explicitly *not* read, so it's still the next character. So when you call it a second time, without having done anything to read that character, it immediately returns the 0-length string up to that same delimiter, over and over again.

Since that behavior is the key difference between `get` and `getline`, if it's not the behavior you want, just don't use it.